# How to limit the time in showDatePicker or showDateRangePicker Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, widget

I need to set Date limit at DatePicker. like i need to set date picker in between 12 Mar,2023 to 20 Mar,2023 and another date i don't want to select from user. user can select date in between 12 Mar,20233 to 20 Mar,2023 from date picker so how can we set that.

```
DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                        context: context,
                        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                        firstDate: DateTime(1950),
                        lastDate: DateTime(2100),
                      );
```

I want to set limit at DatePicker based on requirement. Is there any way to set it. like any Property or any third party package?

Comment: there is a third party package https://pub.dev/packages/time_picker_widget

Comment: you can use `minDateTime` and `maxDateTime` properties in `dateTimePicker`

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Isn't it just the `firstDate` and `lastDate` that you mean?

Comment: `firstDate` and `lastDate` is not a dynamic solution. that mean you set static period. but if we want 10 or 20 days from today.. so how can we set that at `firstDate` and `lastDate` (dynamically) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily set `Date` range in `Date Picker` defining `year, month & day.`

```
 final DateTime pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: DateTime(2021, 3, 15),
          firstDate: DateTime(2021, 3, 12),
          lastDate: DateTime(2023, 3, 20),
        );
```

Comment: `firstDate` and `lastDate` is not a dynamic solution. that mean you set static period. but if we want 10 or 20 days from today.. so how can we set that at `firstDate` and `lastDate` (dynamically)?

Comment: @Harsh you can make it like that just fine, like `lastDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 10))`

Comment: @Harsh you can make all thing dynamic.. But initial date should be between firstDate and lastDate. May be you are new in development. Answer is clear in above. Why do all new comer in stackoverflow want complete solution? Just use your brain.